# Testing Database Connection in Jboss

Tags: postgresql, jboss, datasource, connectivity

I have done necessary configurations by adding JDBC driver in modules, creating modules.xml and then adding necessary datasource configuration in standalone.xml file. I want know if it is done successfully. Is there any way to check that. Is there any way to test database connectivity. My jboss server is running on a linux system and postresql db server is running in another VM instance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can test database connectivity by the following steps:

1. Go to the `JBOSS_HOME/bin` folder and execute `./jboss-cli.sh`. This opens the JBoss CLI.
2. Enter:

   ```
   connect
   ```
3. Enter:

   ```
   /subsystem=datasources/data-source=name_of_your_datasource:test-connection-in-pool
   ```

The `name_of_your_datasource` is the name of the datasource in your `standalone.XML`.

You should see something like:

```
{"outcome" => "success","result" => [true]}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in Wildfly 23. I'm using a domain rather than standalone.